# Declare NULL values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I would like to create a SQL table using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` comande.
I have previously created a table with an attribut (column) FLOAT like:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    foo INT );
```

So now I can use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` comand. 
In the file I want to load, missing values are codded as 'NA'. When I run this command 'NA' values are translated as '0' and not as NULL values which is the mysql standard for missing values.

My question is: How I can declare to mysql that 'NAs' are missing values.

Appologize if this is a current topic but as I am not a SQL specialist I was not able to find the answer to this question.

Thanks in advance,

Marc

Comment: Please check the linked question. I believe there's no other way than coding it in a per-column basis (using `nullif()`or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file.csv'
INTO TABLE table_1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@foo)
SET foo = NULLIF(@foo, 'NA')
```

Given the file `path/to/file.csv` has the following contents

```
foo
1
2
3
NA
4
NA
NA
```

Here is what you'd see in your table after loading the data

```
mysql> select * from table_1;
+------+
| foo  |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
| NULL |
|    4 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you. A problem remain because NAs have been translated into 0s. Maybe I could create first a `VARCHAR()` column, then use `SET foo = NULLIF(@foo, 'NA')` and finally, translate my column as an integer.

Comment: What do you mean by "translated into 0s"? Do you have `NA` or `0` in your file?